# Yii2: Disable ActiveForm Ajax Validation on field blur

Tags: yii2

How disable Yii automatically(validation onblur) ajax validation?
I want to validate only after pressing the submit button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `enableAjaxValidation` to validate your form and at the same time do not want to trigger the ajax validation on every `blur` of the field once you type into it. You only want to trigger the validation on Submitting the form.

To do this with `ajaxValidation` your main options to be used are

- `validateOnBlur` that is the `ActiveForm` option you need to turn it off by passing `false` as value to the option.
- `validateOnChange` either in the `ActiveForm` options or you can specify it under the `fieldConfig` option of the `ActiveForm` to apply on all fields. You need to turn it off by passing `false` as a value.

The `validateOnBlur` will disable the validation if there is no value typed into the field, if you type in some text and then blur out it will trigger validation and to disable that we need to use the `validateOnChange`.

Your form configurations should look like below

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin ( [
        'id' => 'my-form' ,
        'validateOnBlur'=>false,
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'validateOnChange'=>false,
] );
```

Comment: `ActiveForm` also has [`validateOnChange`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$validateOnChange-detail) property.

Comment: Yeah you are right i used it quite a while ago in a project where client required the same thing i used the `fieldConfig` @rob006 just checked back and you can even add it to the main options array. just updated the answer too so that it isnt misleading.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute called [$validateOnBlur](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$validateOnBlur-detail) which reads:

> Whether to perform validation when an input field loses focus. If
>   yii\widgets\ActiveField::$validateOnBlur is set, its value will take
>   precedence for that input field.

Set it to `false` since default is `true`. For example:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'validateOnBlur' => false
]);
```

Comment: added but does not help $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'order-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,   'order-form' => false,
              'validateOnBlur' => false,
           ]);

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It should work, I tried myself when I wrote this answer. Is there JavaScript code added to your form perhaps?

Comment: $('#reg_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').load('/campaign/register/');
});  Only this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable ajax validation completely, set enableAjaxValidation in your form to false:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false
]);
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$enableAjaxValidation-detail

Comment: I do not want to disable ajax validation.I want the ajax validation to work only after I click on the subtit button.